# hyperlinked wallpaper

Tags: hyperref, wallpaper

I have been using

```
\usepackage{wallpaper}
\ULCornerWallPaper{0.1}{image.jpg}
```

I wonder if there is a way to add a hyperlink to the image so that by clicking on the image, a URL opens.

Comment: Sorry Marco.  I have not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on the given definition of `\ULCornerWallPaper` by `wallpaper` I would define a new command. This new command has an extra mandatory argument. Making the picture "clickable" is done by the command `\href`.

The package `mwe` provides the example picture and loads also `blindtext` for filling text.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mwe}
\usepackage{wallpaper}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\newcommand{\ULCornerWallPaperWithLink}[3]{%
  \AddToShipoutPicture{%
    \AtPageLowerLeft{%
      \parbox[b][\paperheight]{#1\paperwidth}{\href{#2}{%       
        \includegraphics[width=#1\paperwidth,height=#1\paperheight,%
        keepaspectratio]{#3}}%
        \vfill%
      }
    }
  }
}

\ULCornerWallPaperWithLink{0.1}{http://tex.stackexchange.com/}{example-image-a}

\begin{document}
\blindtext[10]
\end{document}
```